# Triggering Pull Request Builds automatically on draft pull requests in Azure DevOps (ADO)

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

If I make a pull request in ADO from one of my branches then any commits I push to my branch automatically trigger the build pipeline:

---

[image: Screenshot from ADO showing automatic build triggered]

---

This is configured in the build validation branch policies on master:

---

[image: Screenshot from ADO showing branch policies for master]

---

But for draft pull requests I need to trigger builds manually:

---

[image: Screenshot from ADO showing manual build trigger]

---

The documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops)) does not mention any distinction between active and draft pull requests. How do I configure my project so that commits to branches in a draft pull requests automatically trigger a build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-143-update#draft-pull-requests):

> Draft **pull requests do not** include reviewers or **run builds by default**
>   but **allow you to manually add reviewers and run builds**. To promote the
>   pull request to a normal pull request, simply click the Publish button
>   from the pull request detail page.

So, it looks like you experience the expected behavior.